# How to post a detail record in an FDQuery with the parent record in insert mode?

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe5, firedac

I`m using two`FDQuery` with master-detail relationship and I encountered a problem:

Using the `CachedUpdates` property and relating each `FDQuery` to an `FDSchemaAdapter`, if call `Insert` or `Append` in the master record and then (with that record in `dsinsert` state) `Insert` and `Post` is called in the detail record, the following error occurs:

> [FireDAC] [DatS] -16. Can not process - no parent row. Constraint [ForeignKeyConstraint].

I know this happens because in the `Post` order the child record is being inserted without a parent record, but in the database the foreign key is postponed.

**So, how do I get *FireDac* to ignore only this constraint without disabling the `DetailCascade` property and keeping the cascade delete / update functionality cached?**

I already tried using `FDSchemaAdapter.DatSManager.EnforceConstraints`, but, the result is similar to disabling the `DetailCascade` property of `FDquery`.

*Note: I am using Delphi XE5*

Comment: Why don't you want to Post your master record? If you are calling Post on the child it needs a key value to keep the master/detail relationship in sync. This can be a temporary value assigned by firedac, but it can't be nothing. Since you care using CachedUpdates nothing is going to the database until ApplyUpdates is called anyway. There is no reason not to let the dataset row be posted.

Comment: @MarkElder, "Why don't you want to Post your master record?" I will do it, but, only in final of process. In Postgres Database, my FK is `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, so, in transaction i can insert details rows without FK errors. I wish I could do the same in cache with firedac.

Comment: but "why" not, what problem does it cause to let the record be posted? If you care about the DetailCascade you must be changing something that you want to cascade down. That can't happen if the relationship between the master/detail rows was not established in the first place, and that can't happen until a master row actually exists. When in insert mode there is no "real" row yet. I have places where I need to immediately Insert/Post/Edit on my master dataset so that I have a real row when adding detail rows.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from editing/posting several times before you apply the updates to the database, so as Mark says, what's the reason you don't want to post the master?

Comment: FireDAC's CachedUpdates allows you to do things like insert or edit multiple master rows and multiple detail rows. But FireDAC needs to have the key with some correct value to handle which detail row is linked to which master row. I suspect you have hooked up the ApplyUpdates to the master dataset's Post event, which won't work in a CachedUpdates situation. As everyone else is stating, you need to post the master row. You can edit it multiple times... add the detail rows... and then apply the updates when everything's done... using some button or control to save the data.

Comment: @MarkElder, @Frazz, @Asbjørn I found that the behavior is easily obtained in the **Berlin** version and later. [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions.DetailServerCascade)
Unfortunately I use the XE5 version and there is no forecast to upgrade because of the high costs.
The reason I do not post the master is mainly the "order of validations". If there are required fields in the child record that is incomplete, the Master `Post` will try to `Post` the Detail and will trigger the error before the parent record validates

Comment: I'm confused by what you are trying to do with the cascading, but I'll offer one more suggestion. The Master/Detail is simply a Range filter that is applied to the detail dataset. You can always apply that filter yourself, or depending on your queries you may not even need the filter. Then you can add rows whenever you want to the detail rows, you just need to keep the key value in sync if it changes.

Comment: @AnselmoMS Can you describe the solution in berlin version?

Comment: @ShaahinAshayeri, I did not try to use the feature in Delphi Berlin. I found it by reading the latest documentation.[link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDFetchOptions.DetailServerCascade)

Comment: I have the same problem here, the DetailServerCascade doesn't work in Tokyo 10.2 :(, at least not with MySQL